# Why such a vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A$ is an linear operator on a real vector spacev $V$.

I wish to prove that if for some $x,y \in V$ such that $x\neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$ and some  $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $b\neq 0$, the following conditions hold 
$$
Ax=ax-by, Ay=ay+bx
$$
then $x,y$ are linearly independent.

Comment: What did you try?  A proof by contradiction would begin by assuming $x,y$ are *not* linearly independent.  Combine the expressions resulting from that assumption with the conditions above involving $a,b,x,y$ and see if this gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose the contrary, i.e., that they are linearly dependent. Then $x=ky$, where $k \ne 0$, so

\begin{align*}
Ax=kAy &\implies ax-by=k(ay+bx) \implies x(a-kb)=y(ak+b) \\
&\implies ky(a-kb)=y(ak+b) \implies ak-k^2b=ak+b \\
&\implies k^2=-1.
\end{align*}

This is impossible as $V$ is a real vector space.

Hence they are linearly independent.